# Можно ли сделать специализацию шаблона на конкретный параметр шаблона C++

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Допустим у меня есть шаблонный класс с двумя параметрами.

```
template <class key, class value>
class HashMap
{
    ...

    size_t HashFunction(const key& k)
    {
        string s = to_string(k);
        size_t n = s.size();
        unsigned long long sum = 0;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
            sum += s[i];
        return sum % mod;
    }

    ...
}
```

И в данном случае `to_string()` со `string` работать просто не будет. И мне нужно будет создать специализацию шаблона. Но как создать специализацию только на параметр `key`?

Я примерно говорю про это:

```
template<>
size_t HashMap<string, LUBOI TIP>::HashFunction(const key& k)
{
    size_t n = k.size();
    unsigned long long sum = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        sum += k[i];
    return sum % mod;
}
```

Comment: На будущее - пожалуйста, используйте для шаблонов С++ метку `шаблоны-с++`, метка `шаблоны` относится к шаблонам проектирования.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы хотите это?

```
template <class value>
struct HashMap<string, value>
{
    size_t HashFunction(const string& k)
    {
        string s = k;
```

Или хотите сделать `HashFunction` шаблонной внутри шаблонного класса?

Есть и такой вариант:

```
template <class key, class value>
struct HashMap
{
    size_t HashFunction(const key& k)
    {
        string s;
        if constexpr(is_same_v<key,string>)
            s = k;
        else
            s = to_string(k);
```

Но учтите, `to_string` не будет работать не только для `string`...

Comment: Ну, например, для `pair<int,int>` :) Проще перечислить, для чего он сработает - тут https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string перечислены все 9 перегрузок...

Comment: да, понял, спасибо!